# Can I set a scope property from a directive's link function?

Tags: angularjs, html, canvas, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm making a directive containing a canvas and I'm having trouble accessing it in all the places I need to. I'm currently setting up the canvas in the directive's `link` and drawing some initial elements on it, but I also need to access the same canvas in my directive's controller to update it. At the moment my directive declaration looks like this:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myCanvasDirective', CanvasDirective);

function CanvasDirective() {

    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.vm.ctx = element[0].childNodes[0].getContext('2d');
        //do some initial drawing using scope.vm.ctx
        //this works
    }

    return {
        priority: 1001,
        restrict: 'E',
        link: linker,
        scope: {
            displayValue: '=displayValue'
        },
        template: '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="80" height="80" />',
        controller: MyCanvasController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    };
};

function MyCanvasController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.draw = function () {
        vm.ctx.strokeStyle = '#808080';
        //vm.ctx is unavailable here despite being attached to scope in linker
    };

    vm.draw();
};
```

How can I get access to my canvas context in `MyCanvasController`? As this directive is going to be used many times on a page thanks to several `ngRepeat`s I'd prefer not to just use `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link function [got a controller instance](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-), even if it wasn't exposed on scope with controllerAs.

```
function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    ctrl.ctx = element[0].childNodes[0].getContext('2d');
    ctrl.draw();
}
```

And

> vm.ctx is unavailable here despite being attached to scope in linker

is because the controller runs before `link`. Although controllers [have `$element` local dependency](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-), all 'when DOM element is ready' logic [should be delegated to `link` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#post-linking-function).

Angular 1.5 encourages the usage of `component` and discourages the usage of `link` for Angular 2 migration reasons. Consider using [`$onInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-) controller method instead for this kind of things in Angular 1.5+.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise `link` happened after the controller - or indeed that you can pass the controller into the link function!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are breaking some of the best practices of encapsulation in your question. You should be setting the strokeStyle inside of the directive containing the canvas.  You can do that by passing an additional attribute and binding in the link.

In answer to your question , you can pass the controller as a parameter to the directive. To pass as parameter:

```
 <my-canvas-directive vmparent="vm"></my-canvas-directive>
```

Access in your link as

```
linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.vmparent.ctx = element[0].childNodes[0].getContext('2d');
  }
```